# How to pass as a parameter DbSet <DerivedClass> if parametr in method declaration - DbSet <BaseClass>

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have several derived classes (let call on of them `DerivedClass`) from `BaseClass`.

I need to pass as a parametr `DbSet <DerivedClass>` to change entity DbSet:

in Library:

```
protected void ChangeEntity (DbSet <BaseClass> list) {

}
```

in Code:

```
DbSet <DerivedClass> list;
ChangeEntity (list); // Compillation error
```

How to pass derived class collection as a parameter?

Comment: Generic. `ChangeEntity<T>(...) where T : BaseClass`

Answer (score 0):

If you only need to alter entity objects then make your ChangeEntity method accept IQueryable type instead:

```
protected void ChangeEntity (IQueryable<BaseClass> list) {}
```

Then you can call it in code:

```
DbSet <DerivedClass> list;
ChangeEntity (list);
```

Comment: Thanks for reply @mr100, but how to use Add method in ChangeEntity body with no retrieving database entities (by invoke ToList (), for example)?

Comment: In such case you need to use approach of Anthony Pegram.